# Security.SecureString parameter does not accept strings

Tags: powershell, passwords, parameter-passing

When passing a string as an argument to this parameter:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[Security.SecureString]$password=$(Throw "Password required.")
```

I get this error when using the `-password` parameter.

> cannot convert type System.String to type System.Security.SecureString

If I don't pass the `-password` parameter, a prompt is shown and it accepts the input.

Comment: What is the question? You require a secure string and pass a string to get this error?

Comment: You answered your own question in the subject (?)

Comment: Someone at some point has to create the SecureString, you can take a string and do it yourself or let the caller do it. But it won't happen automagically.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't pass a string; you have to pass a secure string

```
function Get-PasswordThing {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Security.SecureString]$password=$(Throw "Password required.")
    )

    Process {
        Write-Host "cool"
    }
}

[string]$password = "hello"
[Security.SecureString]$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
Get-PasswordThing -password $securePassword

# inline
Get-PasswordThing -password (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to take the password as a String and then convert it to a SecureString within your function.

```
Function DoSomething {
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]$password=$(Throw "Password required.")
)

$password = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

#your script continues here
}
```

Comment: this works brilliant. there must be other way though cause i managed to make it work without conversion once.

Comment: the downside being that the password would be visible in clear text if executed from the command line